# How to get rid of the Section name in RadGridView grouping

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, radgridview

I have RadGridView with group.

This function receive `IReadOnlyCollection<RadListDataItem> files` (represent simple strings):

```
    private DataTable GetTable(IReadOnlyCollection<RadListDataItem> files)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
        table.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Property Value1", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Property Value2", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Property Value3", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Section", typeof(string));
        table.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            AddTableRow(table, files[i].Text);

        return table;            
    }

    private DataTable AddTableRow(DataTable tataTable, string file)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

        tataTable.Rows.Add(false, "Option1", "", "", "", fileInfo.Name);
        tataTable.Rows.Add(false, "Option2", "", "", "", fileInfo.Name);
        tataTable.Rows.Add(false, "Option3", "", "", "", fileInfo.Name);
        return tataTable;
    }
```

And this is the result:

[image]

1. As you can see i have section named Section and after that my file name - is it possible to remove the Section and show only the file name (i try but it doesn't work) ?
2. In each option i have 3 fields but i didn't find out how to add header to each column and because each option is with different headers

Comment: Can you post your RadGrid definition?

Comment: By saying definition what do u mean ?

Comment: How do you declare your RadGridView?

Comment: Just drag this control into my form